# Difference between time shared and space shared algorithms

Tags: algorithm, multitasking

I just came across this term "time shared and space shared algorithms". I couldn't get much information about it in the web. Can anyone shed some light on these terms, specially on `space sharing`?

Answer (score 7):

In my understanding, the terms time-sharing and space-sharing refer to the way the resources of a machine are shared among computational tasks.
For instance, several processes typically take turns in accessing the CPU. This is time-sharing, because over a period of time, we observe more than one process utilizing the resource.
On the contrary, when we assign cores of a CPU to individual processes, we observe more than one process only by looking at more than one core, thus the term space-sharing. A definition from [1]:

> Space-sharing: The machine may be partitioned into sets of processors
>   (clusters). Each cluster is allocated to a single job that is allowed
>   to run to completion (RTC).
>
> Time-sharing: More than one job may be
>   allocated to a cluster, in which case each job runs for some quantum
>   of time before being preempted to allow other jobs to run.

A more recent, but less broad definition of the terms can be found in the context of a Cloud environment [2]:

> assign specific CPU cores to specific VMs (a space-shared policy), dynamically distribute the capacity of a core among VMs (time-shared policy)

Both definitions refer to exclusive access (until a logical task is done) to as space-sharing, while interwoven access to a resource (during a logical task) is referred to as time-sharing.

[1] A. B. Downey, “Predicting Queue Times on Space-Sharing Parallel Computers.,” IPPS, pp. 209–218, 1997.

[2] R. N. Calheiros, R. Ranjan, A. Beloglazov, C. A. F. De Rose, and R. Buyya, “CloudSim: a toolkit for modeling and simulation of cloud computing environments and evaluation of resource provisioning algorithms,” SPE, vol. 41, no. 1, pp. 23–50, Aug. 2010.

Answer (score 6):

*Time-sharing* is probably referring to the concept of sharing executing power (such as CPU, logical processor, GPU) by many users (such as OS processes, threads, network requests).

*Space-sharing* is likely to mean sharing memory space (hard disk, RAM, database) by many different users (such as [in-place algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm), executing threads)

A space-sharing algorithm would achieve its goal by re-using the space (storage) allocated for the input data structure, in other words it may not allocate any additional space during it's execution.